# How to find whether the camera is in use?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

Is there any way to find whether the Android **Camera** is in use in code?

Answer (score 4):

> *Is there any way to find whether the android camera is in use?*

Yes, `Camera.open()` will give you an Exception if Camera is *in use*.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html),

```
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

Comment: Thanks.If it is found that camera is already in use then how can I use the camera? Is it right to release the camera in the catch block and then again try to open it?

Comment: @user1414146 You have to wait till the other application is done with camera :) and then retry.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a really old question, but I stumbled upon it with a google search wondering about the same thing. With the newer versions of android, you can register the `CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback` to determine if the camera is in use or not. Here's some example code:

```
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;

    // within constructor
    // Figure out if Camera is Available or Not
    CameraManager cam_manager = (CameraManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    cam_manager.registerAvailabilityCallback(camAvailCallback, mHandler);


    CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback camAvailCallback = new CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback() {
    public void onCameraAvailable(String cameraId) {

        cameraInUse=false;
        Log.d(TAG, "notified that camera is not in use.");

    }

    public void onCameraUnavailable(String cameraId) {

        cameraInUse=true;
        Log.d(TAG, "notified that camera is in use.");

    }
};
```

Comment: Note, there is a bug in android 5.1 that this might be broken - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=164769 . For those versions, you'll have to call ```cam_manager.getCameraIdList()``` to get the service properly initialized before you can registerAvailabilityCallback.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this question is being asked several times, once you start to your own activity or application camera itself will be released as activity running for camera will be go in pause state.

Comment: But if he is running a background service, then the Camera application might be at the front while he runs his code.

Comment: Not all apps or code behaves this way, although it's what recommended for foreground apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this method.if it returns true then camera is still in use by some app.

```
public boolean isCameraUsebyApp() {
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (camera != null) camera.release();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then show toast to user to restart the device as the camera needs restart.