# How do I notified when camera is used or opened by any other application

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I want to get notified whenever any other application opened or accessed camera. I already know that I can check `Camera.open()` and its exception. but for that I have to check every time using service but it drain battery so I want whenever opened camera just notified me and get its package name. I already read these.

[How to find whether the camera is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220288/how-to-find-whether-the-camera-is-in-use)

[How to check if camera is opened by any application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862621/how-to-check-if-camera-is-opened-by-any-application)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using callbacks provided by the API of `Camera2`.

In your `CameraManager`object you can attach a `CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback` which will notice you when the `camera` object is being used or not.

About `AvailabilityCallback`:

> A callback for camera devices becoming available or unavailable to
>   open.
>
> Cameras become available when they are no longer in use, or when a new
>   removable camera is connected. They become unavailable when some
>   application or service starts using a camera, or when a removable
>   camera is disconnected.

You can research more information about it in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html)